# How do I cast a float using merge in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query

```
MERGE Time_Tracker AS target 
USING 
  (SELECT
    USERID,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '19000101', TotalBreakTime)) / 60 AS ColumnWithBreaksCount
  FROM BreaksTable
  WHERE CONVERT(date, StartTime) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  GROUP BY USERID) AS source 
ON target.USERID = source.USERID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET BREAKS = source.ColumnWithBreaksCount;
```

Here the output that I get is `0` in my breaks column, but the time difference is `10` seconds, when I change `DATEDIFF(minute, '19000101', TotalBreakTime)/60` to `DATEDIFF(second, '19000101', TotalBreakTime)`, it shows me a `10` in my `Breaks column`. Here I want to show the time difference in both minutes followed by seconds(like `0.10`), My breaks column is of `float` type.

Please let me know how can I do this.

Below is my resultant tables

[image]

Thanks

Comment: what would be your result if it was > 60 minutes?

Comment: Your issue is because of integer division. DATEDIFF returns and int and you are dividing by 60. You can easily fix this by making 60 a decimal. divide by 60.0

Comment: good catch @SeanLange

Comment: Also, really you should never use float as a datatype if you are doing math calculations. It is an inexact datatype and it will round.

Comment: @SeanLange, that's awesome man... please don't mind me asking this, is there a way that I can limit this to 2 decimals like `X.XX`, when I try `CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),SUM(DATEDIFF(Second, '19000101', TotalBreakTime))/60.0)`, the actual result `0.16666` is getting rounded to `0.17`